# Xamarin iOS - Simulator View is not refreshing

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, simulator

I have a simple piece of code built in Xamarin for iOS in my ViewController :

```
    void LogMessage (string message)
    {
        logText.Text += string.Format("\n{0}", message));
    }
```

where logText is:

```
    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UILabel logText { get; set; }
```

The code is being called, the Text property of the logText is being updated properly, but in iOS Simulator I see no change at all. I tried replacing `UILabel` with `UITextView` but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to update the UI from a background thread, it will not work.  To force the update on the UI thread, try this

```
InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {  
    logText.Text += string.Format("\n{0}", message));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this call is always on UI thread anyway... Another side problem is that Xamarin is constantly loosing connection with iOS simulator. I am running OS X 10.10